# Suggest a best algorithm to encrypt XML file in C#.NET?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, cryptography

I have to encrypt XML file and send in network to place in a private server.
My other application will decrypt and import to SQL the file by giving the actual Public key.

Could you please suggest me best way for this.

**File**: XML Type
**Possible size**: Up to 250 MB
**Technology**: C#.NET 2008

Comment: Whatever you do: Please **do not try to invent your own encryption scheme**. There are so many custom schemes suggested building on System.Security. Cryptography classes ("just use AES, it's simple...") that are fundamentally broken and provide merely security-by-obscurity (in the best case!). Use any standard mechanism that has been around for years and analysed many times.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [XML encryption](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlenc-core/). It is supported directly in .NET through the [EncryptedXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.encryptedxml.aspx) class.

There is an example on MSDN here: [How to: Encrypt XML Elements with Asymmetric Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229746.aspx).

Note that you should use the public key to encrypt and the private key to decrypt (and not the other way around as you wrote in the question).

Answer (score 2):

Upload the file using SSL/TLS (e.g., with HTTPS or a [Socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx)+[SslStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx)) and let the server require the client to present an X.509 client certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the [RijndaelManaged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged.aspx) class.  [This](http://www.obviex.com/samples/Encryption.aspx) is a good example of its use.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) is more the AES Algorithm.

Comment: thanks SwDevMan81,
Is it possible to encrypt Xml file and at the time of opening it should asked for decrypt key..?

Comment: karthik - Not exactly sure what you are asking.  You will need to maintain the key somehow that was used for encrypting the file in the first place.  That same key will be needed to decrypt the file.