# in what format/file to store application data

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a desktop application developed in c# language that has some games that the users play and the App will store their names, scores and other information on the client computer, currently I am using an xml file to store the info of the user, but a drawback is that the user can edit the file manually and mess with it by editing their scores or name.
I want to store the info so that the users can not manually edit it, so what file format should I use or should I encrypt the data before storing in the file.
My file is stored in the C:\Users\jobs\AppData\Local folder

tnx

Comment: Why not just encrypt your xml document? [Encrypt XML_1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652483/suggest-a-best-algorithm-to-encrypt-xml-file-in-c-net) [Encrypt XML_2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017534/c-sharp-encrypt-xml-file)

Comment: If it's just about protection against tampering with the file, you could sign it like shown in [this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229745(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: encryption seems rather confusing, what if i use a binary file to store user info????

Answer (score 1):

If you need some basic protection against an average PC user you probably want to use something really simple, like this:

```
// data for example
var data = new XElement("gamedata",
    new XElement("player", new XAttribute("name", "t0taln00b"),
        new XElement("score",
            new XAttribute("game", "bite your elbow"),
            new XAttribute("score", 9000),
            new XAttribute("progress", "19 %"))
        )
    );

// set up encryption.
// You probably will want to do this once at program startup and store Key and IV globally

var rnd = new Random(12562);
var keysize = 128;
byte[]
    Key = new byte[keysize / 8],
    IV = new byte[keysize / 8];
rnd.NextBytes(Key);
rnd.NextBytes(IV);

// lets encrypt

using (Aes aes = new AesManaged() { Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7, KeySize = keysize })
{
    aes.Key = Key;
    aes.IV = IV;

    using (Stream file = new FileStream("save.xml.aes", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    using (Stream encrypter = new CryptoStream(file, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        data.Save(encrypter);
}

//and decrypt

using (Aes aes = new AesManaged() { Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7, KeySize = keysize })
{
    aes.Key = Key;
    aes.IV = IV;

    using (Stream file = new FileStream("save.xml.aes", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    using (Stream decrypter = new CryptoStream(file, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
    {
        var loaded = XElement.Load(decrypter);
        Console.WriteLine(loaded.ToString());
    }
}
```

Please note that this would be an extremely weak encryption. Keys generated by `System.Random` cannot be strong, and a whole encryption code can be revealed with tools like .NET Reflector.

If you need really strong encryption i would suggest having something like a webserver which encrypts the file with an asymmetric encryption and keeps the private key secure. This will not absolutely prevent a hacker from reading the file, but at least will make you totally sure that he cannot modify its content.

Comment: tnx for the answer Diligent Key Presser, how if store the text in a binary file  and then read and write to that file

Comment: 1. For good key generation use `RNGCryptoServiceProvider Class` instead of `System.Random`. 2. This answer will provide from the casual attacker which is probably all you need. But a sophisticated attacker will be able to obtain the key and make changes to the XML file.